# Scala - How to implement functions returns this.type with other dimensions of implementations

Tags: scala, oop, generics, types, polymorphism

Here's the scenario. I want to implement a class with a type member, for example, a list on elements of type E. In this class, we have a method which create a new list depending on the parameter, and we have two implementations, BigList and SmallList.

All looks good. But still, I want to specialize some implementations on the type E. For example, we have IntList, and there's some more operations on it. Here's the problem.

When I try to use `take` in IntList, what I hope is to get back a IntList, not a List[Int], sort of like it returns the magic `this.type`. Assume that the BigList and SmallList implementations are independent from the value of type E, which means if I rewrite the method `take` in IntList, it will be identical, except for the return type, and I don't want to duplicate that implementation. I know the BigList and SmallList are not IntList themselves, but I'm having trouble modeling this, maybe this is not the right way, this is just an example to show the usecase. One possibility is to use f-bounded polymorphism like `BigList[E, This <: BigList[E, This]]` for the BigList can represent all kinds of List, IntList, and so on. But I didn't get it working, and it sort of complexes things up.

What's the ideal way to achieve this?

```
class List[E](val head: E, val tail: List[E]) {
  def take(n: Int): List[E] = {
    if (n < 5) new SmallList[E](this.head, tail.take(n - 1))
    else new BigList[E](this.head, tail.take(n - 1))
  }
}

class BigList[E](head: E, tail: List[E]) extends List[E](head, tail) {
  ...
}

class SmallList[E](head: E, tail: List[E]) extends List[E](head, tail) {
  ...
}

class IntList(head: Int, tail: List[Int]) extends List[Int](head, tail) {
  def intSum: Int = ...

  def take(x: Int): IntList = {
    if (n < 5) new SmallList[E](this.head, tail.take(n - 1))
    else new BigList[E](this.head, tail.take(n - 1))
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you have to use BigList[Int] and SmallList[Int] in take method of IntList.

Comment: you mean there's no better way? I can only duplicate the code of take in every specialized subclass?

Comment: I'm no expert, but it seems idiomatic in Scala to use implicits to simulate extension of a type's behavior.

Comment: F-bounded polymorphism is the answer. Go read the the description in the Twitter Scala school and take another stab at it.